# Tool to construct 3D maze for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, quartz-composer

I want to construct a 3D Maze tha will appear on the iPhone screen but not in the typical above-the maze view but in a Wolfenstein walking inside-around the maze fashion.. Excuse my terminology but I'm quite new to this :)

My questions are the following:

**What tools should I use to build my 3d maze? XCode's OpenGl or Quartz Composer?**

Given that I want a fairly simple design is there some even simpler tool I can use to design the maze and then import it in my Objective-C project to integrate user/iphone interaction to this?

***More importantly though:*** Regarding the user's movement around the maze, it will involve some elaborate motion event handling and not your typical click left/front/back/right arrow to move around.. Does that affect in any way the tool I will be using to construct my maze or is this irrelevant?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I hope you realise you've just made all this sound a LOT simpler than it really is. There's no "tool" for building a 3d maze that comes with Xcode. And "XCode's OpenGL" isn't a tool - it's a programming library for doing 3D graphics with (you still have to write the code).

Comment: The answer really depends on what you want to achieve... Have you tried Unity?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/wolfenstein-3d-iphone-source-code.html)'s a link to Wolfenstein 3D Open Source code, if you want to chek it.

Comment: I'd recommend Unity too, @MMM.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone. I will check out Unity 3D. Just one question: Can't I simply create ONE 3d object (just a cube) and then through coding populate an X-Y grid by placing each cube at specific cells? Maybe it's kind of a naive question but I'm just tying to figure out how 3d design works when it comes to not just creating one object but populating a whole area of specific dimensions and at specific positions..

Comment: Yeah, you can do that with Unity. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could (and probably should) do it with [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/). In fact, somebody already [has](http://www.starscenesoftware.com/realmaze.html).

Comment: thanks for the interesting link Elliot, this is the type of maze I'm talking about although much much simpler when it comes to graphics..